# Div not on absolute left of page

Tags: css

I'm working with a div that isn't positioned on the absolute left of the page, all I get is [this](http://pasteht.ml/dL52W).
Is there a way I can fix this? I've tried using many methods.

CSS:

```
#Hello {
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

[Result](http://pasteht.ml/vr736)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html, body { padding : 0; margin : 0; }
```

Comment: what this man said (not the other one, don't use reset stylesheets, keep it clean will ya:)

Comment: @myfunkyside To be fair, that's what I said, I just added a bit of extra info to help the OP

Comment: @ScottBrown - yeah I know, just bustin your balls a bit:) but this man was a minute faster so I wanted to give him credit

Comment: There's nothing necessarily *horribly* wrong with resets; I'd rather put __normalize.css__ in a project, than a reset (cuts down on the number of selector rules in play, while achieving sane browser defaults).  But as for raw CSS, those and `* { box-sizing : border-box }` are the ones at the top of practically all of my projects, Normalize or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }` to your styles. A common technique is to use a reset stylesheet [like this](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) to avoid these default browser styles.